# check DB table's records, if it's match the data or not

Tags: php, laravel

I am having a hard time to solve this problem. Trying to check DB record and compare it to fresh data. And in records in DB. if there is any data that is not match the fresh data. Then `delete()` the old data from DB. I tried a couple ways to achieve this:

I tried it with `whereRaw`

```
 $check = Plan::whereRaw("plan_name", "!=", $val->textContent)->first();
 $check->delete();
```

it's finding the unmatched data but there is an error popping.

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'plan_name limit
>   1' at line 1

Also I tried it with the `where`

```
 $check = Plan::where('plan_name', '=', $val->textContent)->first();
 if($check){
    // do nothing;
 } else {
      $check->delete();
 }
```

`where` is not doing anything. no errors, but also it doesn't delete if data unmatched.

Both ways are not worked for me.

Comment: `whereRaw` requires a full raw `where` query - read the docs at https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#raw-methods closely.

Comment: What's the problem with `where`? Any errors? What's the value of `textContent`?

Comment: `where` is not doing anything. no errors, but also it doesn't delete if data unmatched. `textContent` is a `string` @azeós

Comment: `$check` will only exists if the `where` finds something. Since the `where` is not working, doing `$check->delete()` won't have any effect because `$check` is empty. Do a `dd($check)` to see what are you getting. Are you sure your query is correct?

Comment: yes it's very much correct. `else { dd($check); }` I did it, but it seems it doesn't run the else part. So i got nothing. @azeós

Comment: Do the `dd($check)` after the `where`, before the `if`.

Comment: yes, I am getting the unmatched data in `dd` @azeós

Comment: Please post the results. You shouldn't get anything if you are using `first()` and the `where()` isn't correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200139/discussion-between-iampanda-and-azeos).

Answer (score 0):

You just want to delete the data which does not match some condition.

It is simple, You don't have to fetch data. you can simple do `where()` then `delete()`

**Example Code**

```php
Plan::where('plan_name', '!=', $val->textContent)->delete();
```